# C# pipe ( | ) equivalent in Powershell for Add-Type imported functions?

Tags: c#, powershell, winapi

I want to call a C# function in PowerShell, but with arguments containing pipes. I can call it this way in C# `SomeCSharpFunction( THING | OTHERTHING, ARG2, ARG3)`, but I can't find a way to do the same thing once I imported the function in PowerShell with `Add-Type`.

The imported function works as expected if I have "single" arguments like this

```
[Imported.Functions]::SomeCSharpFunction($Arg1,$Arg2,$Arg3)  #This works
```

But I can't set `$Arg1` to be `$Thing | $OtherThing` , because PowerShell interpret the pipe differently, nor can I call the functon

```
[Imported.Functions]::SomeCSharpFunction( $Thing | $OtherThing, $Arg2, $Arg3) #This doesn't
```

I tried a few other separators in PowerShell, tried to somehow escape the | character (`|, \|, '|', none did the trick ) , tried to send a PowerShell array `@($Thing,OtherThing)` )

My online searches about this were unsuccessful, as search engines seemed to ignore the | character.

A workaround I'm currently using is to define a C# Wrapper function that accepts multiple arguments, and then calls `SomeCSharpFunction` with these arguments "merged" with a | , but I'm searching for the proper way to do that if there's any

---

### Example

In my PowerShell Script, I used Add-Type to "import" a function from Kernel32, like this

```
$Signature = @"
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(uint dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, uint dwProcessId);
"@

$Kernel32 = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $Signature -Name "Process" -Namespace Win32Functions -PassThru
```

I can then call it inside PowerShell with `$Kernel32::OpenProcess($DesiredAccess,$InheritHandle, $ProcessId)`, which works perfectly if my arguments are "unique".

Now, in C# I can call it this way (note that I already set PROCESS_VM_OPERATION and PROCESS_VM_READ to their respective uint values)

```
OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, false, vProcessId)
```

I'm trying to achieve the same thing but in PowerShell, as explained in the General part.

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with C#, is the pipe in this case the operator for or?

Comment: @Persistent13 I'm not extremely familiar with it as well, but according to my researches it should be a bitwise or, for example `0001 | 0010 = 0011` . and this more detailed [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx(v=VS.80).aspx) provides the example `0xf8 | 0x3f = 0xff`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To combine the (enum) values, you should use the + operator (if the binary values don't overlap) or the -bor operator (Boolean or, if they do overlap.

If you have constants from the same enum, you can do something like this, too:
[FlagsEnumType] "Value1, Value3"

[here](http://www.latkin.org/blog/2012/07/08/using-enums-in-powershell/) is a link to a post about using enum values in PowerShell.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about the -bor operator in PowerShell !  Since `|` is also the *boolean or* operator in C# (I used to call it *bitwise operator* but *boolean operator* seems more common), it definitely is the right way to go, and it's safer than + if they overlap. Thanks !

Comment: The article about enums was also a really good read, that'll definitely be useful. Thank you again :) !